# problem occured with findByIdAndUpdate i need solution for this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my code:

```
async updatePaymentMethod({name,method,inheritToSubsidiaries,invoiceEmail,requireProjectId,billing_address: {city,country,organization_name,postal_code,references:{attn,co,reference},region,street_address,},}) {
    if (method == "INVOICE") {
      try {
        const { company } = await this.context.dataSources.user.getCompany();
        const paymentMethod = await Company.findByIdAndUpdate(
          { _id: company._id },
          
          {
            $set : {paymentMethod: {method,invoiceEmail,inheritToSubsidiaries,requireProjectId,},name,billing_address: {city,country,organization_name,postal_code,references: {attn,co,reference},region,street_address,},}},
          {
            new: true,
            useFindAndModify:true,
          }
        );
        console.log(paymentMethod)
        return {
          success: true,
          message: "ok",
        };
      } catch (e) {
        return {
          success: false,
          message: "failed",
          e,
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

I need to update the particular fields like `billing_address{references:{att> this Only}}`

But when I update the document, all fields go to null, and updated values show.

I used $set to update values but got null for all fields excluding passed values in mongoose.
[image: Before Update]

[image: After Updated]

Comment: The reason for this is because you are passing even fields you have no intention of updating, and whose values are undefined, into the set function. Filter only the properties with values you want to update into your set function.

Comment: tried like that also but no changes Only getting a null and note: im using Graphql